# VSCode Angular 5 Chrome debugger issue - matches blank ? - and holts

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

[image]

After one of the updates suddenly stopped working.
I am debugging through Chrome developers tools for now.

> ng serve 
>   works well and the app is running perfectly.

But, I want to debug with VSCode again..
Tried several configuartions that result in this same issue above.
2.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

  {
    "name": "ng serve",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
      "webpack:/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
      "webpack:/src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
      "webpack:/*": "*",
      "webpack:/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ng test",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
  },
  {
    "name": "ng e2e",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
    "protocol": "inspector",
    "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/protractor.conf.js"]
  }
]
```

}

2.

```js
// {
//    // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
//    // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
//    // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
//    "version": "0.2.0",
//    "configurations": [  
//        {
//            "name": "Launch Chrome with ng serve",
//            "type": "chrome",
//            "request": "launch",
//            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
//            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
//            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
//                "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
//                "webpack:/*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"
//            }
//        },
//        {
//            "type": "chrome",
//            "request": "attach",
//            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
//            "port": 9222,
//            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
//        }

//     ,]
// }
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "webpack:/*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Attach Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "port": 9222,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome (Test)",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome (E2E)",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/protractor.conf.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Disabled all extensions except 
Debugger for Chrome
Visual Studio Team Services

port 4200 is not found in use

> netstat -a -n -o

How should I change the launch.json and restore debugging ability through VSCode?

Comment: are you using lunch or attach  ?

Comment: I want to return using launch.. attach is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem happen when the port `9222` is beging in use because this port is the defualt port for debug mode so just use another arbitrary number port for launch type just like my launch.json file

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "port": 4040
        },
        {
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "attach",
          "name": "Attach to Angular",
          "port": 9222,
           "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

> until the time of writing this answer this consider a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/635) and
>   will be fixed in future releases.

Happy Coding

Comment: thanks for your response. 
that option is set in my settings as well and working at the second option of configurations in comments..
I don't understand why it stopped running new instance of chrome on launch

Comment: I just found the problem is the port 9222 just use different port will work fine @TzviGregoryKaidanov

Comment: As per version 1.25.1 it still is has the same problem.

Comment: You just need to add theport numbe I got this problem  and I have fixed like this and it working now

Comment: Seems that as you said adding this line --> "port": 4040 <-- to the "name": "Launch Chrome", configuration works. thanks! flagged it as an answer

Comment: @TzviGregoryKaidanov can you consider flag this question as answered ? , thanks :)